# Can I run WCF on top of WebAPI?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

For a work project, I'm building an application consisting of a frontend SPA (Aurelia), a WebAPI backend for that SPA, and a multitude of web service WebAPI projects contained in existing applications. (This application will perform data aggregation - it's a dashboard for our clients to show relevant information from many sources.)

Immediately, I was faced with some challenges. Using WebAPI, we wanted to expose the web services as REST endpoints. This works well for client applications and is very open. However, making server-to-server calls in .NET, I wanted to abstract away the REST calls and simply provide a method-based interface (so I could call, say, `new MyWebServiceClient().getOrders()` or something like that); I also did not want to have to duplicate data model classes across solutions, or worry about deserializing one JSON model type to another type. (Blegh.)

To achieve this goal, I've created an internal nuget package that a) provides access to the data model classes used in the service via the assembly, and b) provides an interface for HTTP calls, abstracting away the JSON serialization and deserialization, like so:

```
public async Task<T> Get<T>(string endpoint, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var builder = new UriBuilder(Properties.Settings.Default.MyEndpointHost + endpoint);
    builder.Query = buildQueryStringFromParameters(parameters);

    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        // After this, we really shouldn't continue.
        var request = await _httpClient.GetAsync(builder.Uri, cancellationToken);

        if (!request.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            if (request.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.BadRequest && request.StatusCode < HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                throw new EndpointClientException("Service responded with an error message.", request.StatusCode, request.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            if (request.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError && (int)request.StatusCode < 600)
            {
                throw new EndpointServerException("An error occurred in the Service endpoint.", request.StatusCode, request.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }

        var json = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The public methods are simply convenience methods, calling that function with the requisite arguments, like this:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<MyModel>> SearchMyModelsByFooName(string fooName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("searchText", fooName));

        return await this.Get<List<MyModel>>("myModel", parameters, cancellationToken);
    }
```

I've had good results with this, although I have to maintain it manually and update dependencies.

However, upon talking to my colleagues, I was introduced to WCF, and it looks as though it solves a lot of the issues I'm trying to solve manually. Looking into this, though, reveals that the setup can be tricky, and we're not sure if it's worth the trouble. (Additionally, we'd have to maintain two APIs.)

Although it's fun, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Is there a way to bolt WCF on top of WebAPI for server-to-server calls only, or have WCF generate data for WebAPI controllers?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use REST, and personally I don't see any reason to do this in a .NET server to server scenario, you could just create a WCF service to expose your data. Then generate proxy classes in your WebAPI that calls the WCF service.

Using svutil to generate the proxy classes make it easy to adapt to changes in WCF "API". And you will have, as you call it, a method based interface to interact with the WCF service/s.

Reference for using svutil: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there a way to do this the other eay around - have wcf call into webapi logic? We already have webapi hooked up and it's the way forward. I don't want to tie logic into wcf. I want it to be a layer that we can remove easily down the line.

Comment: So you want to have one REST API and one WCF (SOAP) exposing the same logic?

Comment: The same models, same logic. We are using services but I feel it would be better to update things in one place rather than two.